# Getting TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' when splitting class functions into multiple cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I am running a decision tree code in Jupyter Notebook and created a class called DTC. Within DTC has multiple functions. In Jupyter Notebook, I have split these class functions into multiple cell by calling `class DTC(DTC): ...` at the top of each function in the cell.

Most of the functions work except for one. Below is the code:

```
class DTC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = None

...

class DTC(DTC):
    def __predict_what(self,data,node):            
        if len(node.children) == 0 :
            return node.output
        val = data[node.data]       
        if val not in node.children :
            return node.output
 
        return self.__predict_what(data,node.children[val])

class DTC(DTC):
    def prediction(self,X):
        Y = np.array([0 for i in range(len(X))])
        for i in range(len(X)):
            Y[i] = self.__predict_what(X[i],self.__root)
        return Y
```

The function prediction() is giving an error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'` when attempt to run. I have diagnosed and found that this is the line with the issue:

```
Y[i] = self.__predict_what(X[i],self.__root)
```

If I remove this, the prediction() function can return `i`. Either that if I remove Y[i] without [i], the function can run too.

To call this prediction() function, I pass in a 2D array of X - `classification.prediction(test_data.values)`

One weird thing is that *the code works with no issue if I run the class and all its function in a single Jupyter Notebook cell*.

Any idea why this occur and what is the fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each Cell is runn as separate statement operating on the same global enviromnet.

The first thing I would say is that what you are doing is horrible - making a class inherit a previous version of itself is not a good way to organise code. It just feels 'hacky'.

As you yourself said, the line giving the error is :

```
Y[i] = self.__predict_what(X[i],self.__root)
```

But in the code you have provided you never set `self.__root`;  It is only ever set to None in your first class statement.

which means when you call self.__predict_what - you are always calling :

```
Y[i] = self.__predict_what(X[i],None)
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, this is a clear explanation. I agree that it is not recommended to do it this way, but I have to in order to describe each of my functions in the markdown in Jupyter Notebook. I don't suppose there is a workaround for this?

Comment: @user3118602 - I have never used markdown in Jupyter so I can't say that there is a better way. I wouldn't use the same class names - but that is just me.